Spreadsheet formula Vertical Horizontal
can anyone help me to solve this. i have this timeline with machine and weekly schedule.

and after that I want to make a dashboard automatically that will show us the machine that have "1" on the same week with the week on dashboard. I already try to use vlookup and index match but still dont get it.

Thank you
I already try the vlookup and index match but stil cant have the right result. Thanks

Have you tried the =FILTER() function? What version of Excel do you have? And what exactly should it look like?

i use google spreadsheet

If you use Google Sheets, then please don't tag Excel: they are not the same thing

This formula maybe does what you need: /requires 365/
=TOCOL(IF(CHOOSECOLS($A$4:$XX$100,MATCH($D$9,3:3,0))=1,$C$4:$C$100,1/0),3)
In D9 there is the week number looking for.
The formula is in cell C11. Replace $XX$100 with the bottom right cell of the table. Also replace in $C$100 the last row value of the table.


actually i still cant, what is the function of 3:3

This a the lookup range means row 3
